# how to do a query using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Here is my db:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class siteids(db.Model):
    website = db.Column(db.String(30))
    siteid = db.Column(db.String(38), primary_key = True)
    included_placements = db.Column(db.String(2605))
    active_units = db.Column(db.String(965))
```

When I do the following I just get column "siteid"

```
@app.route('/grunge')
def grunge():
    queries = siteids.query().all()
    return render_template("siteids.html", values = queries)
```

can somebody suggest me some link where I can read how do the queries work in SQLAlchemy? I am beginning with this and I am getting crazy :-(

Comment: I learned with this one https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world

VEEERY good tutorial, can not recommend it enough. If you are only interested in

Comment: thanks a lot man. I have already found the mistake. Now I am trying to know how to close the posts in stackoverflow :D

Comment: It'd be great if you type an answer to your own question. Then see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96281/how-to-close-a-question-in-stackoverflow-com

Comment: There's a "delete" link just below your question.

Comment: is above code giving you error? and if you want to learn about how to make queries than this official document is enough. http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/

Answer (score 0):

so the way to get the other columns is not about the query - in this case - but about the html.

Is just about doing the following in siteids.html:

```
{% extends "father.html" %}
{% block content %}
  {% for basura in values %}
    <p>
      {{ basura.website}} y este es el siteid {{basura.siteid}}
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```